# React-Native Android CodePush setup not downloading updates

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-code-push

I'm having trouble setting up CodePush into my React-Native Android application. On my dashboard, it's not showing that any apps have downloaded the update or installed it.

NOTE: iOS Codepushing works for this mobile app, just not Android.

I currently have my codePush options set up like this:

```
let codePushOptions = { 
   checkFrequency: codePush.CheckFrequency.ON_APP_RESUME,
   installMode: codePush.InstallMode.ON_NEXT_RESUME
};
```

---

### Things I have done:

1. In your `android/settings.gradle` file, make the following additions:

   include ':app', ':react-native-code-push'
   project(':react-native-code-push').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app')
2. In your `android/app/build.gradle` file, add the `:react-native-code-push` project as a compile-time dependency:

   ...
   dependencies {
   ...
   compile project(':react-native-code-push')
   }
3. In your `android/app/build.gradle` file, add the `codepush.gradle` file as an additional build task definition underneath `react.gradle`:

   ...
   apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
   apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"
   ...
4. If you are integrating Code Push into React Native application please do the following steps:

Update the `MainApplication.java` file to use CodePush via the following changes:

```
...
// 1. Import the plugin class.
import com.microsoft.codepush.react.CodePush;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

    private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        ...
        // 2. Override the getJSBundleFile method in order to let
        // the CodePush runtime determine where to get the JS
        // bundle location from on each app start
        @Override
        protected String getJSBundleFile() {
            return CodePush.getJSBundleFile();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
            // 3. Instantiate an instance of the CodePush runtime and add it to the list of
            // existing packages, specifying the right deployment key. If you don't already
            // have it, you can run "code-push deployment ls <appName> -k" to retrieve your key.
            return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                new MainReactPackage(),
                new CodePush("deployment-key-here", MainApplication.this, BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            );
        }
    };
}
```

Here is a picture of my MainApplication.java file

[image]

---

I know there is also [this portion](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/docs/setup-android.md#background-react-instances) of the setup instructions that I don't know if I need to do or not. I tried to implement it but I get an error because this code is not like the sample documents at all that I have in my files.

I'm not quite sure what this is either:

```
public class MyReactNativeHost extends ReactNativeHost implements ReactInstanceHolder {
  // ... usual overrides
}
```

### Edit 2 - index.js file

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import codePush from "react-native-code-push";

import App from './app/config/app';

let codePushOptions = { 
    checkFrequency: codePush.CheckFrequency.ON_APP_RESUME,
    installMode: codePush.InstallMode.ON_NEXT_RESUME
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AppName', () => codePush(codePushOptions)(App));
```

Comment: Can you see the update in the dashboard?

Comment: Can you please share your index.js

Comment: @AshwinMothilal the update is on the dashboard with only the iOS devices listed as downloaded

Comment: @AnuragChutani I've updated my question to post the index.js at the bottom. I would like to reiterate that iOS Codepush's work. Just not android.

Comment: Try using install mode immediate like this on click a button codePush.sync({
                        updateDialog: true,
                        installMode: codePush.InstallMode.IMMEDIATE
                      });

Comment: @AshwinMothilal I can do this to test but I don't really want update dialogue's. Will report back if it pops up but I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: Everything seems fine, just check your deployment key once and logcat with Codepush as filter to see logs, also check if you are running application in debug mode.

Comment: Anything worked?

Comment: So I actually found out I was using an iOS project trying to CodePush to Android. What confused me is I saw an android device popup in the project so didn't know they were different. But after creating an Android specific Project to do CodePush, I didn't have any issues and it works fine. I appreciate your help. @AshwinMothilal

Answer (score 4):

I added the following to my android/app/build.gradle and it work as a workaround. I'm guessing this is likely an android gradle plugin issue. There seem to be a bunch of undocumented breaking changes in AGP 4.1+ that affect React Native.

under android { defaultConfig { I added

`resValue 'string', "CODE_PUSH_APK_BUILD_TIME", String.format("\"%d\"", System.currentTimeMillis())`